# How can I listen for all notifications sent to the iOS NSNotificationCenter's defaultCenter?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I want to listen to all notifications dispatched to the defaultCenter.  Both public and private.  Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use NSNotificationCenter's [`addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-SW1) OR [`addObserver:selector:name:object:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-CHDCIGGB) method and pass nil for the name and object.

## Example

The following code should do the job:

```
- (void)dumpNotifications {
    NSNotificationCenter *notifyCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notifyCenter addObserverForName:nil 
                              object:nil 
                               queue:nil 
                          usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification){
                             // Explore notification
                             NSLog(@"Notification found with:"
                                    "\r\n     name:     %@"
                                    "\r\n     object:   %@"
                                    "\r\n     userInfo: %@", 
                                    [notification name], 
                                    [notification object], 
                                    [notification userInfo]);
                          }];
}
```

## Docs

Here are the docs on [`addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-SW1).  In particular, see the *name* and *obj* parameters.

> **addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:**
>
> Adds an entry to the receiver’s dispatch table with a notification
>   queue and a block to add to the queue, and optional criteria:
>   notification name and sender.
>
> `- (id)addObserverForName:(NSString *)name object:(id)obj
>   queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue usingBlock:(void (^)(NSNotification
>   *))block`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *name*
>
> The name of the notification for which to register the observer; that
>   is, only notifications with this name are used to add the block to the
>   operation queue. **If you pass nil,** the notification center doesn’t use
>   a notification’s name to decide whether to add the block to the
>   operation queue.
>
> *obj*
>
> The object whose notifications you want to add the block to the
>   operation queue. **If you pass nil,** the notification center doesn’t use
>   a notification’s sender to decide whether to add the block to the
>   operation queue.
>
> *queue*
>
> The operation queue to which block should be added. If you pass nil,
>   the block is run synchronously on the posting thread.
>
> *block*
>
> The block to be executed when the notification is received. The block
>   is copied by the notification center and (the copy) held until the
>   observer registration is removed. The block takes one argument:
>
> *notification*
>
> The notification.

Comment: This no longer works on macOS Monterey, even if the sandbox is disabled.