# iOS SDK - Catch whatsapp (or other apps) incoming notifications

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, sdk

my customer want an app that catch whatsapp (or other apps) incoming notification and send these notifications to a specified email address.
With iOS SDK can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I think its not possible. anyhow if you achieve it, then apple will reject your app.

Comment: I agree with @Bhupesh. This is against iOS sandbox and impossible without jailbreak.

Comment: posible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954905/how-can-i-listen-for-all-notifications-sent-to-the-ios-nsnotificationcenters-de