# Can I get all existing Notification Center messages using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

I'm wondering is there a way to get all of the messages in Notification Center.

I already know how to post a message, but I don't know whether I can get the messages posted by other Apps into my App for usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), nil, { (_, observer, name, _, _) in
        print("Notification \(name) received")
        }, nil, nil, .deliverImmediately)
```

But be careful, there are a lot of notifications. :-)

Please consider also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954905/how-can-i-listen-for-all-notifications-sent-to-the-ios-nsnotificationcenters-de?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot access this information from an app