# WKWebView Media Player fullscreen detection

Tags: ios, ios8, wkwebview

Before iOS 8, the `UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification` notification was sent any time a media player went to fullscreen from a UIWebView. In iOS 8, this doesn't happen and some have suggested to listen for the `AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification` notification instead. This doesn't appear to be sent from WKWebView. Listening for the `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` notification doesn't work because it's fired for all windows that are added (including things like ad networks)

Bottom line, I've been working on this all night and I can't seem to figure out how to determine if a video was opened in full screen with a WKWebView. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: To confirm, I created a blank project. Added a UIWebView and the `AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification` listener to it and it got triggered when I played a video and it entered full screen. I switched that UIWebView to a WKWebView and that notification was no longer triggered.

Comment: The best I could find was the `UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification` for determining when another window took over. This, luckily, didn't fire when my banner ad was created. I then set a `windowBecameKey` variable and tested for it on the `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification`. The only hiccup I saw that could make this a little fragile is that `UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification` fires again just before the fullscreen window hides. If, for some reason, it fires afterwards, it would probably break things.

Comment: can find any the actually avplayeritem instance from WKWebView https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This workaround seems to work on iOS8 & iPhone 6

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ...

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowBecameHidden:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification object:nil];

    return TRUE;
}

- (void)windowBecameHidden:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UIWindow *window = notification.object;

    if (window != self.window) {    // Not my own window: assuming the video window was hidden, maybe add some more checks here.

            // Add code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Detect when avplayer show and play can you help me please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview

Answer (score 0):

I just need to do the same. I listened all notifications with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7955014/1271424 and found: there are no notifications about fullscreen mode at all, except notifications about creating new window (_UIWindowContentWillRotateNotification) and about MPRemote (MPRemoteCommandTargetsDidChangeNotification).

Tested on iPad, 8.1.1