# Is there an onSave hook for Parse local datastore (on iOS)?

Tags: parse-platform, hook, nsnotifications, local-datastore

While [Parse Cloud Code](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-onsave) provides an on-save hook that lets you perform custom actions **on the backend** when objects are saved, their iOS SDK doesn't have any similar hook for when objects are saved into the local datastore with `-save(Eventually)*` methods.

I would like changes in data to drive my custom actions, such as update the application's UI, refreshing a table etc.. How could this be done? Are there any `NSNotification`s that you could observe?

Comment: I tried looking for notifications using the snippet here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7955014/590767 but didn't manage to find any useful notifications sent by Parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot would depend on if your local "afterSave" is dependent on confirmation of a save in the cloud or not.  Consider the following two examples.

You can *pinInBackgroundWithBlock* and send a notification as well as save eventually.  The notification would send right away unless there was an error pinning.  Keep in mind that your *saveEventually* could still fail.

```
[myObject pinInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if( succeeded ){
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"localBeforeSave" object:myObject];
        [myObject saveEventually];
    }
}];
```

Or you can just use a block to send a local notification once you can confirm that the save eventually completed.

```
[myObject saveEventually:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"localAfterSave" object:myObject];
}];
```

Comment: Yes I think notifications is definitely a good way to do this.